# Django - How can I create POST with foreign key defined in URL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I wonder how can I create object POST with defined ID. Let's assume that I have for instance table `User` with columns `id`,`name` and table `Object` with columns `id`,`id_users`,`sth` where `id_users` is a foreign key of `id` from `User` table. I would like to have such URL `/users/{id}/object` and I would like to create object for user with defined ID in URL.
For example this is my URL `/users/1/object` (`url(r'^users/(?P<myID>[0-9]+)/object/$', views.UserObject)` - should be okey) and body of POST:

```
 {
      "id": 2,
      "sth": 123
 }
```

In this case it should be added to my database:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "id_users": 1,
  "sth": 123
}
```

For `User` with `id` equals `1` we have created `object` with `id` equals `2` and `sth` equals 123.

I don't know what my view should look like?
I always did `POST` in this way:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def ObjectList(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have deleted duplicated posts, because I have explained here how my database and relations between tables look like. I also specified what I would like to achieve.
Any suggestions how can I deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])

```
def object_list(request, myID):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ObjectSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(id_users=myID)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I get response `{
  "id_users": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}`

Comment: I had to change `models.FloatField()` to `models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)` in my class. Now it works, thank you.

Comment: id_users shouldn't be in your serializer at all, since you're sending it in the url as a parameter. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but it seems a bit of a roundabout way to achieve things.