# Django - How to GET value from table where I don't have foreign key in table from which I want to GET object?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Let's assume that I have for instance table `Object1` with columns `id`,`id_users` where `id_users` is a foreign key of `id` from `auth_user` table and table `Object2` with columns `id`,`id_object1`,`sth`, where `id_object1` is a foreign key of `id` from `Object1` table.`ID` of Object1 and Object2 is automatically incremented in mySQL database.

I would like to have for instance such URL `/users/{id}/object2/?sth=123` and I would like to get object from `Object2` table where `{id}` is `id` of the user from `auth_user` table (in this case is equals `2`) and `sth` is equals `123` in `Object2` table in appropriate field.

Let's assume this is my model:

```
class Object1(models.Model):

    id_users = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)

class Object2(models.Model):

    id_object1 = models.FloatField()
    sth = models.FloatField()
```

I had quite similar problem which was solved in this post - [Django - How can I create POST with foreign key defined in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221103/django-how-can-i-create-post-with-foreign-key-defined-in-url) but in this case I don't have `foreign key` in table from which I want to GET object. I have no idea what is the best way to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any relationship between the fields, say `object1__id_users = 2` and `object2__id_object1 = 2` like that?

Comment: If you mean that `id_object1` is a foreign key of `id_users` from `Object1` then there isn't. `id_object1` is a foreign key of `id` (which is not defined in model because it's automatically incremented in database (maybe this is wrong?)) from `Object1` table.

Comment: then it should be like this. `id_object1 = models.ForeignKey(Object1)` right?

Comment: If `id_object1 = models.ForeignKey(Object1)` is a equivalent where `id_object1` in `Object2` model is a foreign key of `id` from `Object1` table then my answer is yes. I supposed that I will have to change my model. At this moment my model is ok? If yes how can I create view for task that I have described in main post?

Comment: What you want is this -> **"get object from Object2 table where {id} is id of the user from auth_user table"** but there is no relationship between user and the object2 table, right?

Comment: Yes, but `id` (in this case `{id}`) of the user (auth_user table) isn't a foreign key in table `Object2`, but in table `Object1`. Exactly as you have written.

Comment: Then object1 table, it would be like `id_users = models.ForeignKey(User)` am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Then would you please update the question with the right tables?

Comment: I'm not sure where I made mistake?

Comment: Well may I post the answer, with columns as you just specified(with ForeignKeys and all)??

Comment: Okey, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand about your dilemma, I think your models should be somewhat like this,

**models.py**

```
class Object1(models.Model):
    id_users = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Object2(models.Model):
    id_object1 = models.ForeignKey(Object1)
    sth = models.FloatField()
```

Then, you asked that the urls should look somewhat like this,
    `/users/{id}/object2/?sth=123`

Then your view should be somewhat like this,

**views.py**

```
def your_view(request, user_id):
    sth = request.GET.get('sth', '')
    sth_instance = Object2.objects.get(sth=sth, object1__id_users=request.user)
    #do whatever you want to do...
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/(?P<user_id>[\d]*)/object2/$', your_view, name='view_name'),
    ]
```

Hope this what you were looking for..

Comment: I will be able to test it in 4 hours and I will answer whether it works. Thanks for your help no matter what.

Comment: Appreciate it buddy